# How to execute my java,cucumber and selenium test cases in heroku cloud platform?

Tags: java, selenium, heroku, cucumber

I am not able to execute my java+cucumber+selenium test cases in heroku cloud platform.Please help me is there in build pack configuration i have to add to my application.

I have even kept the chrome driver in corresponding path.And even though it is not working.?

Comment: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

Comment: Are you getting an error, or are the tests not running at all? Heroku runs `mvn test` by default, which might not execute your integration tests (you might need `mvn verify`)

Comment: I have to execute my cucumber+selenium test cases, which needs a browser while executing the test cases.So, how can i achieve this.?

Comment: Heroku is providing some build-packs for adding the chrome browser.I am using pure java+cucumber+selenium technologies to execute those in heroku cloud platform with the help of maven.